# How do I delete forward on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I know this:

- `Fn` + `backspace` - "del" key (delete letter to the right) <-- where's the `Fn` key in the MBP?
- `Alt` + `backspace` - Delete last word
- `Command` + `backspace` - Delete whole line

Now... there is no `Fn` Key on a MacBook Pro. What key combination should I use, or it's a matter of simply: It's not possible?

Comment: There is a Fn key on the MacBook Pro - it's in the lower-left-hand corner. All MacBook Pros have it.

Comment: What keyboard is physically installed? The function key is lowest and leftmost on the US keyboard. It might be moved on some international keyboards.

Comment: @bmike Yeah, it must be missing on some international keyboards; I looked at balexandre's profile and from that checked the Danish and Portuguese MacBook Pro keyboards and they both had Fn keys, so it must be some other version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, you can also use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to trigger a forward-delete, at least in most places.  Some older apps may not support it, apparently.

Comment: Cocoa apps and other apps that use standard system text fields should accept the Ctrl-D shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

I use <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>  to **kill** the rest of the line, effectivly deleting all text after the cursor on that line.

Answer (score 3):

### MacBook Pro 2006 Non-Unibody Fn Key

Edited based on the comment:

[image: 2006 Non-Unibody MacBook Pro Fn Key Location]

---

---

### MacBook Pro 2011 Fn Key

I suspect you've just missed it, as noted in CajunLuke's comment. I checked several international keyboards as well.

---

#### 13"

[image: 13 inch MacBook Pro Fn Key]

---

#### 15"

[image: 15 inch MacBook Pro Fn Key]

---

#### 17"

[image]

Comment: I have a pre-unibody MBP 15''

Comment: @balexandre Ah, sorry, for some strange reason I thought you wrote that it was a 2011 MacBook Pro.

Comment: @balexandre I've edited my answer to show the location of the Fn key on the 2006 non-unibody MacBook Pro. What key do you have there instead?

Comment: +10 for the awesome pictures. It must be an international keyboard or have had the keycaps replaced for Fn to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

My MacBook Pro had a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key at lower left, and the [pictures](http://switchtoamac.com/site/apple-introduces-keyboard-changes-in-the-new-macbook-pro-models.html) I can find confirm this (the keyboard changed several times and mine was an early model).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the [software keyboard viewer](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8362.html) in case your hardware key for function is moved or you might have an international keyboard instead of the standard US layout.

Answer (score -1):

Once again Keyboard Maestro comes to the rescue.  I set Shift-Delete as a hotkey to trigger a fn-delete keystroke.  Works a charm.

Keyboard Maestro is worth the price for the time saved.  For instance, I set `1 to backspace twice and type my email address,`2 returns my wife's email address, etc, etc.